# Apply a custom function to multidimensional numpy array, keeping the same shape

Tags: python, numpy

Basically I want to map over each value of a multidimensional numpy array. The output should have the same shape as the input.

This is the way I did it:

```
def f(x):
    return x*x

input = np.arange(3*4*5).reshape(3,4,5)
output = np.array(list(map(f, input)))
print(output)
```

It works, but it feels a bit too complicated (`np.array`, `list`, `map`). Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call your function on the array:

```
f(input)
```

Also, better not to use the name `input` for your variable as it is a builtin:

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return x*x

arr = np.arange(3*4*5).reshape(3,4,5)
print(np.alltrue(f(arr) == np.array(list(map(f, input)))))
```

Output:

```
True
```

If the function is more complex:

```
def f(x):
    return x+1 if x%2 else 2*x
```

use `vectorize`:

```
np.vectorize(f)(arr)
```

Better, always try to use the vectorized NumPy functions such as `np.where`:

```
>>> np.alltrue(np.vectorize(f)(arr) == np.where(arr % 2, arr + 1, arr * 2))
True
```

The native NumPy version is considerably faster:

```
%%timeit
np.vectorize(f)(arr)
34 µs ± 996 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)


%%timeit
np.where(arr % 2, arr + 1, arr * 2)
5.16 µs ± 128 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

This is much more pronounced for larger arrays:

```
big_arr = np.arange(30 * 40 * 50).reshape(30, 40, 50)

%%timeit
np.vectorize(f)(big_arr)
15.5 ms ± 318 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
np.where(big_arr % 2, big_arr + 1, big_arr * 2)
797 µs ± 11.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: This works for the demo example of `x*x` but doesn't for weird function with complex logic...

Comment: What complex logic?  For example, you can use all arithmetic operations,the same way.

Comment: `def f(x):
    return x+1 if x%2 else 2*x`  ... Of course you can go around with `np.where` etc.. but you see the point, not hard to come up with horrible (recursive?) functions where it will simply not work at all.

Comment: was going to mention `np.vectorize` but you just did... :)

Comment: `np.vectorize` it exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot! :)